# Practicando, haciendo un ventana con un boton

Tags: java, ventana

Soy novato en Java y mi primer código, es hacer una ventana modal JFrame que se pueda modificar el fondo y tenga un boton, pero no lo consigo, no se porque:

```
package practica1;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;

public class pantalla extends JFrame{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       pantalla v = new pantalla12();
       v.setVisible(true);
       v.setBounds(300,400,2000, 1000);
       v.setTitle("hola");
       v.setBackground(Color.green);
   }    
}
```

pantalla12.java

```
package practica1;

public class pantalla12 extends pantalla {

  JButton boton;
  JPanel panel;

  this(panel);
  panel.add(boton);

}
```

Solamente me sale la ventana modal sin el fondo pero lo demás no.

Porque será?

Gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero para modificar el background de un JFrame debes colocar la siguiente linea.

```
getContentPane().setBackground(aqui el color que quieres);
```

Para agregar componentes como JPanel, JButton, JTextField, primero debes instanciarlos e inicializarlos para poder agregarlos. Ejemplo:

Para un boton:

```
JButton elBoton = new JButton("Soy un Boton");
```

Para un panel:

```
JPanel elPanel = new JPanel();
```

Luego ya los puedes agregar

```
add(elBoton);
add(elPanel);
```

El metodo setVisible() te recomiendo que lo dejes siempre a lo último, despues de haber hecho todas las modificaciones.

Aquí te dejo un breve ejemplo:

```
package Ejemplos;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class VentanaConBoton extends JFrame {

private JButton boton;

public VentanaConBoton() {

    setTitle("Ejemplo");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    boton = new JButton("Boton Ejemplo");
    boton.setBounds(50, 50, 180, 180);

    add(boton);

    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    VentanaConBoton v = new VentanaConBoton();

}
}
```

Al ejecutar quedaria así:

[image: Al ejecutar quedaría así:]

Answer (score 0):

Al final me salio bien:

pantalla.java:

```
package practica1;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class pantalla extends JFrame{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      pantalla v = new backend();
      v.setVisible(true);
      v.setSize(2000, 1000);
      v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      v.setTitle("Primera Practica");
   }    
}
```

backend.java:

```
package practica1;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class backend extends pantalla{
   JPanel panel;
   JButton boton;
   JLabel texto;
   public backend() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      JLabel texto = new JLabel();
      JButton boton = new JButton();

      add(panel);
      panel.add(boton);
      panel.add(texto);
      panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
      boton.setText("Soy un boton");
      boton.setBackground(Color.green);
      boton.setSize(500,500);
      texto.setSize(40,40);
      texto.setBounds(10,10,100, 40);
      texto.setText("Soy un texto");
   }
}
```

Pero quiero agrandar los objetos, pero no va porque pasa?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

A tu panel debes colocarle el Layout en null para que el setBounds de los componentes sirva adecuadamente.

```
panel.setLayout(null);
```

Con esa linea ya tu setBounds de los componentes le modifica el tamaño y lo coloca en la posicion que le indicas.

Comment: por favor no coloques múltiples respuestas, así no funciona la comunidad; borra una de las 2 y la que dejes dale editar y mejora el contenido de la misma